# Question about brute force running time

Tags: algorithm-design

Quite a simple question though I can't wrap my head around it:

The key size is: $n$

Because it's brute force it tries each possible key once from $0$ to $n$, but in my head that just makes the run time $O(n)$, though it's surely meant to be a polynomial or exponential. The decryption message is of size $x$ though I'm not sure it is relevant. Would it be because the key is of size $n$, but they must also try all keys from $0$ to $n$ make it $2^n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say key size is $n$, we consider $n$ in bits, n-bit key size. For example, AES has 128, 192 and 256-bit keys sizes. Therefore, we have $2^{128}$ key to search for AES-128 and that is exponential, $ \mathcal{O}(2^n)$

---

In cryptography, we use also a security parameter that measures the input size of the problem.  The security parameter is represented as unary representation ( $\lambda-\text{times }1)$ so that the complexity of the cryptographic algorithms will be polynomial time.

For RSA like systems, when we say the security parameter is $1^\lambda$, the $\lambda$ represents the number of bits of RSA modulus $n$. So the positive integer $n$ must be between $0,\ldots,2^{\lambda-1}$.

**Note:** We usually don't say AES (and other block ciphers) have security parameter 128, we just say 128-bit key.